# How to output a different color for commands in a bash shell terminal?

Tags: bash, macos, shell, terminal

I'm trying to figure out how to get various commands (such as `touch`, `git`, or `echo` to display a different color in the terminal. I installed the [Dracula theme](https://draculatheme.com/terminal/) but the instance of it on my computer does not look the same, save for the background, text, and directory color. I have tried to install a few other themes where I have seen photos of command text displayed in a different color, but none of them work for some reason.

I'm on mac os sierra running the latest version of terminal. I also have have the display of ANSI colors enabled. I would really love to get this to work, as it would allow me to interpret my console more efficiently.

Comment: For basics, take a look here: http://www.owsiak.org/?p=3338 I also suggest to watch this one - if you want to accelerate your productivity in shell (from time to time they have nice discounts) - http://www.owsiak.org/?p=2177

Answer (score 1):

You can use tput command to assign color values to variables and use them in your output, like in below example:

```
GREEN=$(tput setaf 2)
RESET=$(tput sgr0)
echo ${GREEN}"HELLO WORLD"${RESET}
```

You can change the value of setaf for different colors